# Can I mention that I left my job to improve my language skills?

Tags: interviewing, germany

I am a non-EU citizen, and I wish to relocate from Estonia to Germany.
Four months ago, I left my previous job to focus on my German skills. It was difficult to work full time and effectively study German.

I am wondering: if HRs notice to the gap, and I specify that I have been studying German, would it be seen as a negative point?

How can I explain it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Studying is perfectly acceptable. Put it in there. Do not leave a gap.

Assuming you are applying to German companies, they will see you studying German as a good thing. You demonstrate planning in both doing that course and having saved enough income to be without a job for that time. I cannot see anything negative about it.

Germans are married to their paperwork. Any certificates you got, attach them.

Comment: Key to this answer is *Put it in there. Do not leave a gap.*

Comment: Not only does it demonstrate planning, it demonstrates a pretty high level of dedication and investment. Someone who spends 4 months studying a new language full time in order to move to that country isn't likely to abandon that, turn around and leave a few weeks/months later because they're homesick or whatever.

Comment: What's wrong with a gap? Does it imply being out of touch?

Comment: Why couldn't you get a job then? There must've been a reason. Maybe it's because nobody wanted to employ you… Maybe the prospective employer also shouldn't. (and various other reasons)

Comment: So take a page from the Brits and "mind the gap"?

Comment: @TankorSmash At least in German CVs, a significant gap implies there is something in your life you want to hide from the employer.

Answer (score 18):

On the contrary!
It's a really positive point! It shows you are dedicated to your goal, which is working in Germany.

Write your CV to add this "gap" stating that you took classes to learn German as if it were another job. It's a formation you took to prepare yourself to your next job, it's an asset!

Answer (score 3):

Just tell them exactly what you told us. As long as the gap is explainable (and reasonable), it is usually fine.

Comment: It’s not a gap: it should be near the top of your CV.

Comment: It's a gap in employment history, but not "a gap" I could have worded that better. I'll edit when I'm on a computer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just mentioning it, I'd even advise you to propose continue the interview in German. Like this you will also demonstrate your motivated and adaptive attitude.